# download attachments larger than 4MB

Tags: office365, azure-ad-graph-api

using the https://graph.microsoft.com/user/{user}/messages/{messageid}/attachments/{attachmentid} I have reached an attachment larger than 4MB. The API is sending a 403 error and I can't figure out how to get the item.

I've tried the paging commands but they only work for drive items, and I am not sure if there is a way to have graph initiate downloading the item directly to the save location.

https://graph.microsoft.com/user/{user}/messages/{messageid}/attachments/{attachmentid}/

I've also tried

https://graph.microsoft.com/user/{user}/messages/{messageid}/attachments/{attachmentid}/$value (same 403 error)

https://graph.microsoft.com/user/{user}/messages/{messageid}/attachments/{attachmentid}/preview [not found error]

Would like a way to stream blocks and or to send partial streams through the request.